# Return view laravel parameters

Tags: parameters, controller, laravel-5.7

how can i send 2 arrays + 1 variable to my view? The last one parameter isnt sendend

```
return view('index', ['array1' => $array1], compact('variable'), ['array2' => $array2]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to send data to view you can do this :

```
$data = array(
'array1' => $array1,
'myVariable => compact('variable'),
'array2' => $array2
);

return view('index', $data);
```